# ASP.NET API: Get XML from content

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api, cxml

I have following ApiController method in my ASP.NET (.NET Framework 4.5.1) app:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]XElement value)
    {   
        ...
    }
```

But when I try to post raw xml in the content via Postman the `value` is always null.

Here is more information from Fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost:54193/api/punchoutsetup/post HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e2d5563a-061b-4ddc-b03b-6f9d4835c535
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.2.0
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:54193
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 1441
Connection: keep-alive

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd">
<cXML payloadID="1211221788.71299@ip-10-251-122-83" timestamp="Mon May 19 18:29:48 +0000 2008" xml:lang="en-US">
  <Header>
    <From>
      <Credential domain="DUNS">
        <Identity>test</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </From>
    <To>
      <Credential domain="DUNS">
        <Identity>test</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </To>
    <Sender>
      <Credential domain="DUNS">
        <Identity>test</Identity>
        <SharedSecret>test</SharedSecret>
      </Credential>
      <UserAgent>Coupa Procurement 1.0</UserAgent>
    </Sender>
  </Header>
  <Request>
    <PunchOutSetupRequest operation="create">
      <BuyerCookie>c64af92dc27e68172e030d3dfd1bc944</BuyerCookie>
      <Extrinsic name="FirstName">Jim</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="LastName"></Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="UniqueName">jim</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="UserEmail"></Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="User">jim</Extrinsic>
      <Extrinsic name="BusinessUnit"></Extrinsic>
      <Contact role="endUser">
        <Name xml:lang="en-US">jim</Name>
        <Email></Email>
      </Contact>
      <BrowserFormPost>
        <URL></URL>
      </BrowserFormPost>
    </PunchOutSetupRequest>
  </Request>
</cXML>
```

Why does it not recognize the xml information?

I see following Exceptions being thrown in the Debug output:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
```

And is there a more detailed log available in Visual Studio to check what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative can be to load the XML as a raw string and parse it into the `XElement`

```
[HttpPost]
public IHtpActionResult Post([FromBody]string value) {
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        return BadRequest();

    Xelement element = XElement.Parse(value);

    //...
}
```

The main problem is that the model binder is unable to bind the provided raw data into the desired model (in this case the `XElement`) and thus sets it to its default value of *null*.

To bind by default, models must have a default parameterless constructor in order for the the model binder to initialize the model. `XElement` does not. Otherwise you would probably need to create a custom parameter binder that knows how to handle `XElement`

Comment: Thanks. But even ‘[FromBody] string value’ is always null

Comment: @Palmi hmm odd. see if `object` works and just convert it to string afterwards,

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. The request is always null whether its an object or string...

Comment: @Palmi Have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: @spierce: Have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: @NutsAndBolts I just posted my solution above. Let me know if you have questions

Comment: @Palmi I just posted my solution above. Let me know if you have questions

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by doing something similar to what @Nkosi was doing by using the XMLDocument class (System.XML).

What worked for me was:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SomeEndpoint()
{
    // parse the string content from the request
    var content = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(content);
    var root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;

    // next, get your values using the XML path relative to the root node in the request
    var example = GetXmlNodeValue(root, "Path/To/Value");
    // then do something with your values and return
    return Ok();
}
```